# How to pass array of function pointers to another function

Tags: c++, arrays, function-pointers

I have got 2 functions:

```
char* odwroc(char* nap, int n) 
char* male(char* nap, int n)
```

I have defined  a pointer to that kind functions

```
 typedef char*(*pointerToFunction )( char*, int );
```

then in used that definition in main:

```
 pointerToFunction ptr1 = odwroc;
 pointerToFunction ptr2 = male;
```

but now I have to create a function which as a first parameter gets array of that pointers to function and I am stuck. I don't know how to define array of pointers to function and how the `modyfikuj` parameter list should look like.

```
void modyfikuj(char* pointerToFunction *pointerArray, int length, char* nap2, int n){ 
}
```

Comment: How would you declare an argument as an array of any other type? As `pointerToFunction` is a type (alias of a type really) it can be used as any other type like `char` or `int`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Like that: `void modyfikuj(pointerToFunction *pointerArray, int length, char* nap2, int n){


}`

Comment: That looks good. Now make an array of the type, and pass it to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pointerToFunction mojefunkcje[] = { odwroc, male};

modyfikuj( mojefunkcje, ...);      // pass the array fo modyfikuj()

void modyfikuj( pointerToFunction* funtab, ...)
{
    funtab[0]( string, liczba);    // call  odwroc( string, liczba)
    funtab[1]( string, liczba);    // call  male( string, liczba)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though the above answer make sense, use of containers such as std::vector will give you more control when passing an array of similar type such as a pointer to a function. Please try below code snippet.

```
#include "vector"
using namespace std;

typedef char*(*pointerToFunction )( char*, int );

typedef vector<pointerToFunction> FUNCTION_VECTOR;

bool modyfikuj( FUNCTION_VECTOR& vecFunctionVector )
{
    // The below checking ensures the vector does contain at least one function pointer to be called.
    if( vecFunctionVector.size() <= 0 )
    {
        return false;
    }

    // You can have any number of function pointers to be passed and get it executed, one by one.
    FUNCTION_VECTOR::iterator itrFunction = vecFunctionVector.begin();
    FUNCTION_VECTOR::const_iterator itrFunEnd = vecFunctionVector.end();
    char* cszResult = 0;
    for( ; itrFunEnd != itrFunction; ++itrFunction )
    {
        cszResult = 0;
        // Here goes the function call!
        cszResult = (*itrFunEnd)( "Hello", 1 );

        // Check cszResult for any result.
    }

    return true;

}

char* odwroc(char* nap, int n); // You will define this function somewhere else.
char* male(char* nap, int n); // You will define this function somewhere else.

int main()
{
    FUNCTION_VECTOR vecFunctions;
    // You can push as many function pointers as you wish.
    vecFunctions.push_back( odwroc );
    vecFunctions.push_back( male );
    modyfikuj( vecFunctions );
    return  0;
}
```